# findall ignoring order parameter?

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to use the following:

```
    $this->Chapter->recursive=1;
    $chaps = $this->Chapter->find('all', array(
         'order'=> array('sequence_number' => 'ASC') 
    ));
    $this->set('chapters', $chaps );
```

to retrieve all my chapters by increasing order, but CakePHP seems to be ignoring the 'order' parameter.  I believe that I have the syntax correct (based on view-source:http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types, which says the following should work:

```
public function index() {
    $articles = $this->Article->find('available', array(
        'order' => array('created' => 'desc')
    ));
}
```

).  The SQL for the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE chapters (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sequence_number INT UNSIGNED,
    title VARCHAR(50)
);
```

and I'm not getting any syntax or run-time errors.  However, the SQL generated by Cake to actually get the chapter records is:

```
SELECT `Chapter`.`id`, `Chapter`.`sequence_number`, `Chapter`.`title` 
FROM `Tutorial`.`chapters` AS `Chapter` WHERE 1 = 1
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

**As a work-around** I'm happy to put an order property on the Model. Since I typically want to retrieve chapters by sequence number I'm fine with adding this to the model:

```
public $order = 'Chapter.sequence_number ASC';
```

Once I do that Cake generates

```
SELECT `Chapter`.`id`, `Chapter`.`sequence_number`, `Chapter`.`title` 
FROM `Tutorial`.`chapters` AS `Chapter` WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `Chapter`.`sequence_number` ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you try something like this, instead:

```
$chaps = $this->Chapter->find('all', array(
     'order' => array('Chapter.sequence_number ASC') 
));
```

*The main difference being this part: `Chapter.sequence_number ASC`*

Comment: @BarryChapman This is an option if the OP chooses not to use a custom `find` condition.  The formatting for this actually comes from [the top section of the same book here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find)...

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right. I misunderstood the question, I was under the impression that the user WAS trying to use a custom find type, but in retrospect, I do not think he was. ++

Comment: @BarryChapman I do hope I read the question correctly, though; when I read your post earlier, I went back through to double check....  Good point about the custom find types earlier, though; the OP still might want to try using those in the future for something...

Comment: @summea - This totally worked!  

I posted here when I got to the point where I thought I'd tried everything that was suggested (although *cough* not the one at the top of the page).  I think I tried just a string, and I tried an array within an array (as I posted above), just not an array of a string :).

(Although the documentation does say "//string or array defining order". )

Comment: @MikeTheTall Glad to hear it!  I think this actually happened to me a while back... because the problem sounded somewhat familiar... :/